# How to count entries in a table?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

Hello I have written an function which calculates the days between the currenttime and a date in the past. So if the difference is greater than 250 i say with the ngif = write old!

So now i would like to count the entries in the table and put them in a alertbox.

Heres my code of the Service an the datediff function

```
this.todoService.getTodos()
  .then(td => {
    for(let i=0; i<td.todos.length;i++) {
      console.log(td.todos[i]);
      td.todos[i]["diffDays"]= this.dateDiff(new Date(),td.todos[i]["time"]);
    }
    this.todos = td.todos;
  })



private dateDiff(date1, date2) {
  const daydiff = moment(date1).diff(moment(date2), "days");
  return Math.abs(daydiff);
}
```

Code of the Ngif

```
 <td><div *ngIf="todo.diffDays >250">old</div> </td>
```

So now i have an alertbox which count the entries of the table.

```
<div *ngIf="todos.length >= 0 " class="Box">
  <div align="center" class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
    <strong>There are {{todos.length}} Entries.</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

So now is the question: What schould i do to count the old entries?

Thanks!

Comment: Call filter on the array, remove ones that are not 'old', and the length of the new array is your answer

Comment: Do you have an example for the my code? I dont get it. it seems very easy but i dont get it

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to this:

1. Create function
2. Init counter
3. Iterate over `todos` and increase counter by 1 if `diffDays > 250`
4. Return counter

Here is approximate code (can differ a little, but I think you will catch the main thought):

```
countOldEntries(): number {
  let counter: number = 0;
  this.todos.forEach(td => {
    td["diffDays"] > 250 ? counter++ : null;
  });
  return counter; // will return the number of 'todos' with 'diffDays > 250'
}
```

If you don't need store this items to new array (for example), the way above is one of the cheapest.

Comment: I cant get it do you have an exact code ? for my code?